# Generate empty row for unused slots

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

I designed a db schema to hold patient appointments. Every hour is divided into equal 15 slots and the last two slots are always kept unused for emergency cases. When printing the appointment list, I need to have all the booked appointments along with empty row for 14 & 15th slot for each hour so receptionist can fill-in the unscheduled appointments by hand in the printed sheet.

appt_schedules:

```
id
slot_id
hour
scheduled_on
```

slots table - contains exactly 15 rows all the time.

```
id
start_time
end_time
```

The following query gives me the expected result except the empty row for 14 & 15th slot.

```
SELECT `appt_schedules`.* FROM `appt_schedules` 
LEFT JOIN `slots` ON `appt_schedules`.`slot_id` = `slots`.`id` 
WHERE `scheduled_on`='2015-04-17' LIMIT 10,10
```

I am also open to schema changes that can result in simple and efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `appt_schedules`.*, `slots`.`slot_id` FROM `appt_schedules` 
LEFT JOIN `slots` ON `appt_schedules`.`slot_id` = `slots`.`id` 
 WHERE `scheduled_on`='2015-04-17'  and `slots`.`slot_id` between 1 and 15
```

Assuming of cours slots.slot_id holds the 15 equal alots as an int 1 to 15

Another way to write it a bit more optimized is:

```
    SELECT `appt_schedules`.*, `slots`.`slot_id` FROM `appt_schedules` 
    LEFT JOIN `slots` ON `appt_schedules`.`slot_id` = `slots`.`id` 
     WHERE `scheduled_on`='2015-04-17'  and `slots`.`slot_id` IS NOT NULL
```

Or even better:

```
    SELECT `appt_schedules`.*, `slots`.`slot_id` FROM `appt_schedules` 
    JOIN `slots` ON `appt_schedules`.`slot_id` = `slots`.`id` 
     WHERE `scheduled_on`='2015-04-17'
```

****BEGIN REVISED EDIT****

If I understand correctly please try:

```
 SELECT s.slot_id, aps.* FROM slots s
 LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
             over(PARTITION BY aps.slot_id 
                       ORDER BY aps.slot_id
                     ,aps.scheduled_on)  AS RowId
      FROM appt_schedules aps) aps
         ON aps.slot_id = s.id
            AND s.slot_id = aps.RowId
WHERE scheduled_on = '2015-04-17'
ORDER BY s.slot_id
```

Once again thanks for removing slos.slot_id....

```
 select * 
   from slots s 
   left join appt_schedules as 
      on s.id = as.slot_id 
  where IFNULL(as.scheduled_on, '') in ('', '2015-04-17')
```

Comment: I tried your queries, but still I couldn't get rows for 14, 15th slot for each hour.  The following query comes closer, but it returns only one empty row set, but I need it for every hour.


select * from slots s left join appt_schedules `as` on s.id = `as`.`slot_id`

Comment: SELECT * FROM appt_schedules

Comment: Looks like you wrote for MS-SQL server. I'm using MySQL. I thought to create empty row in the db itself for those values to simplify things.

Comment: In order for null valued rows from the appt_schedule table to appear in your query you need to derive your sql statement from the slots table and join it to the appt_schedule table.  Unless there is another column which will uniquely match up the individual appointments with the 15 slots per slots.id I would suggest adding an int column to the appt_schedules table that would count the 15 available appointment slots and could be used to match up the slots.slot_id.

Comment: It is already there. slot_id in appt_schedules references primary key field, 'id' of the slots table.

Comment: Then you simply need to derive your query from the slots table and left join appt_schedule

Comment: Now that slots.slot_id is no longer confusing the issue is your select * from slots s left join appt_schedules as on s.id = as.slot_id where isnull(as.scheduled_on, '') in ('', '2015-04-01') should work fine